# PDF File generated using jsPDF doesn't show on Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, jspdf

I'm currently working on a project, where I have to generate a report on a button click using jsPDF. The code works perfectly fine in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but doesn't work on Microsoft Edge. The PDF document loads in an iframe in the background but the page is white and blank. Can anyone suggest a solution for displaying the PDF correctly in Microsoft Edge?

**Note:** I cannot share the code because it causes copyright infringement. I'm sorry. Also, the debugger shows **`no such interface supported`** error when I click the button.

Thanks in advance.

Here's a sample code I've created to demonstrate the issue:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from '../dummy.json';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-pdf',
  templateUrl: './create-pdf.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-pdf.component.css']
})
export class CreatePDFComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    var columns = [
      {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
      {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
      {title: "Country", dataKey: "country"}, 
  ];

  var rows = [
      {"id": 1, "name": "Shaw", "country": "Tanzania"},
      {"id": 2, "name": "Nelson", "country": "Kazakhstan"},
      {"id": 3, "name": "Garcia", "country": "Madagascar"},
  ];

  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
  doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
      styles: {fillColor: [100, 255, 255]},
      columnStyles: {
        id: {fillColor: 255}
      },
      margin: {top: 60},
      beforePageContent: function(data) {
        doc.text("Header", 40, 30);
      }
  });
      let blob = doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
      var newWindow = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      newWindow.document.write('<title>My PDF File Title</title>');    
    }   
  }
```

Comment: We need a sample code for reproducing and testing the issue. Without any sample code we cannot make any guess what exactly you are doing in your code to achieve the desired result. Also let us know, which exact version of MS Edge browser you are using for test.

Comment: Hi Deepak, I'm working for a company, and the client has got the code copyrighted. So I cannot share it with you. My Microsoft Edge version is 41.16299.15.0 and EdgeHTML version is 16.16299. If you need any more details, please let me know. I hope you understand why I cannot share the code.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I can give you the code I've used for generating the pdf. 
`if (isPrint) 
{
   let blob = doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
   var newWindow = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
   newWindow.document.write('<title>My PDF File Title</title>')
}`

Comment: We do not need any confidential information. You can try to develop a sample which can reproduce the same issue with minimal code. It can help us to understand the issue in better way. I can see that your Edge version is old. I suggest you to update your Windows OS with latest updates which helps to update the Edge browser and then again try to make a test.

Comment: If possible for you then try to make a test with navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, defaultName); It can help you to open blob on IE and Edge browser. let us know about your testing results. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh772332(v%3Dvs.85) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveOrOpenBlob

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, it still doesn't work in Edge, it works fine in Google Chrome. I can give you a sample piece of code. It is not part of my project, but I've created it for your reference, I'll put it as an answer to the question. Please take a look.

Comment: You can try to post the sample by editing the original post. After adding the code in original post please leave a comment about it. I will again try to check it and try to make a test using it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I've edited the question and added the sample code. Please have a look.

Comment: We tested the issue and able to reproduce it. Here I want to confirm with you that did you made a test with navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, defaultName); ? It can help to solve the issue for IE and Ege browser. If you did not made a test then I suggest you to check it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I tried using navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, defaultName);, but it produced the same result. It too couldn't display the content.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I want to preview the generated PDF document **without downloading it**, because I have created another option to download it. Please do note it if it wasn't clear from the post.

Comment: I can see that you had posted the another similar kind of question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59025698/trying-to-open-pdf-file-in-edge-shows-somethings-keeping-this-pdf-file-from-op Are both issues same? If yes, please refer the answer I posted on that question. if not please let me know about the status for this thread.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, Yes that question is related to this issue. In this case, only a blank page was displayed in Edge. But now `Couldn't open PDF` error shows.

Comment: I suggest you to do follow up on any 1 case as it is difficult to follow up about the same issue on multiple threads. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT, I'll do the needful.

Comment: A small update to this question:

I tried reproducing the error in the new Microsoft Edge browser, based on the OpenSource Chromium Engine by Google. I was not able to reproduce the issue. So I guess this is an issue related to the Edge browser and this error occurred only because Microsoft Edge(old) doesn't support PDF Files in base64 format. I thank all of you who helped me with suggestions and walkarounds to fix the problem, albeit in a different manner. Thank you, friends!