# Trying to open PDF File in Edge shows "Something's keeping this PDF file from opening" error

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, jspdf

I'm trying to open a PDF file in the Microsoft Edge browser. The PDF file is generated using jsPDF library in Angular 8. The code I've written is given below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from '../dummy.json';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-pdf',
  templateUrl: './create-pdf.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-pdf.component.css']
})
export class CreatePDFComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    var columns = [
      {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
      {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
      {title: "Country", dataKey: "country"}, 
  ];

  var rows = [
      {"id": 1, "name": "Shaw", "country": "Tanzania"},
      {"id": 2, "name": "Nelson", "country": "Kazakhstan"},
      {"id": 3, "name": "Garcia", "country": "Madagascar"},
  ];

  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
  doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
      styles: {fillColor: [100, 255, 255]},
      columnStyles: {
        id: {fillColor: 255}
      },
      margin: {top: 60},
      beforePageContent: function(data) {
        doc.text("Header", 40, 30);
      }
  });
      let string = doc.output("datauristring");
      let file = this.dataURLtoFile(string,"Report.pdf");
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      var newWindow = window.open();
      newWindow.document.open();
      newWindow.document.write('<html><body><object data = "'+url+'" width = "100%" height = "100%" type = "application/pdf"></object></body></html>');    
    }
    dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
      var arr = dataurl.split(','),
          mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
          bstr = atob(arr[1]), 
          n = bstr.length, 
          u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

      while(n--){
          u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
      }
      return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
  }   
  }
```

When I run the code in Google Chrome, the file opens. But when I try it in Microsoft Edge, the screen shows **"Couldn't open PDF, something's keeping this PDF from opening"** error. I tried clearing the cache of the browser, but still, the error shows. Can anybody please help me by giving a solution?

N.B. I'm attaching a screenshot of the error message for your reference.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKM5G.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried with other browsers like Chrome or Firefox

Comment: any errors in edge console(or developer tools)???

Comment: @HirasHaris Yes. I tried with Google Chrome. It works fine in Chrome. The problem shows only in edge

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS, I cannot see any specific error in the console.

Comment: if it was a polyfills problem that should have showed up... lets see, I see [github issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/521) , if the version is edge 11 i think there might be an issue with promise... i don't know if this is helpful but try adding a polyfill for promise

Comment: Ok @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS, I'll check and tell you. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS, I tried adding `promise-polyfill` npm package, but still, it doesn't fix the issue. Can you please suggest some other solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the same issue you had posted 4 days ago.

[PDF File generated using jsPDF doesn't show on Microsoft Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58969549/pdf-file-generated-using-jspdf-doesnt-show-on-microsoft-edge)

I again try to make research based on new error and I found that this error may occur if you had installed any other pdf viewer for viewing the pdf. It can interrupt the Edge and can cause this error.

You can try to Refer following points may help to fix this issue.

(1) Set Microsoft Edge as a default PDF viewer.

(2) Delete Cache in Microsoft Edge.

(3) Repair Microsoft Edge.

For detailed steps, you can refer link below.

[Couldn’t open PDF in Edge, Something’s keeping this PDF from the opening](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/couldnt-open-pdf-in-edge-somethings-keeping-this-pdf-from-the-opening)

Comment: Hey Deepak, this is related to that issue that I've posted 4 days ago. Now I think this is some issue related to the Edge browser. Anyway, I'll check the link, follow the steps and let you know the results. Thank You!

Comment: I followed the steps but it **didn't** fix the issue.

Comment: Try to manually open any pdf file in your Edge browser and check whether it is able to open the file or not. Also try to run the same code on other machine to verify the issue. It can help to know whether issue is producible on all machine or it is related to specific machine.

Comment: This issue was posted by the QA Team of my company. They found the bug while testing in Edge version 44. The version of Edge I'm using is 41. So I don't think it is a machine-specific bug. And about what you said, when I try to open a PDF file in my computer using Edge, it opens. There's no issues. But when I pass a base64 string to the iframe src, it doesn't render.